# How to Implement a Checksum Algorithm Based on a Written Description

Tags: delphi, pascal, checksum

I'm working on a project that is asking me to treat data coming from satellites and some frames are ended by a checksum. The ICD lists the checksum as being a "Binary 16-bit sum of data words (2 bytes sum, first byte is MSB), ignoring carry."

From what I understand I made this function in Pascal that takes the length of the frame and the frame itself and returns an unsigned 2 byte integer :

```
function T_Appli.checksum_calc(tab: array of byte; length: cardinal): word;
var
  checksum : word;
  i : cardinal;
begin
  i := 0;
  checksum := 0;
  while i < length-2 do
  begin
    checksum := checksum xor tab[i] xor (tab[i+1] shl 8);
    i := i+2;
  end;

  if i = length-2 then
    checksum := checksum xor tab[i];

  Result := checksum;
end;

end.
```

I thought I understood what the description asked me to do... But now I'm not so sure. And finding a good description of the algorithm is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: `tab: array of byte` needs to be `const tab: array of Byte`.

Comment: Why are you `xor`'ing everything when the description asks for a "sum" instead? It sounds like you are supposed to treat every 2-byte pair as a word and just sum them together, but that is not what you are actually doing. Try this more like this instead: `checksum := checksum + PWord(@tab[i])^;` It would be really useful if you would provide a [mcve] that includes a sample byte array and what the expected checksum is supposed to be.

Comment: Data is big-endian. Try `checksum := checksum + tab[i] shl 8 + tab[i+1];`

Comment: Or: `checksum := checksum + ((Word(tab[i]) shl 8) or tab[i+1]);`

Comment: @W.Chang The data is in Big Endian so that is not a mistake. I should have mentioned that beforehand, my bad.

Comment: @DexTr I knew. That's why `shl 8` should be to `tab[i]`, not `tab[i+1]` as in your code.

Comment: Ask for some examples of data (bytes) and the corresponding checksum so you can verify what you're doing

Comment: @RemyLebeau I figured XOR'ing the bytes was the same as adding them while ignoring the carry. I can try to find a reproducible example but it's hard to come by at the moment.

Comment: `xor` is bit-wise and different from `+`. Actually, the difference is always `2(a and b)`. That is, `a xor b` equals to `a + b - (a and b) shl 1`.

Comment: Have a read on [Fletcher's checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher's_checksum#Straightforward). Edit your Q to include the original full description. Find out if really is a **checksum** and not instead a 16-bit [**CRC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) - both come in many flavors.

Comment: @DexTr, "first byte is MSB" means LE. Why not just go `array of Word` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, perhaps because of "binary sum". However, this doesn't compute with "ignoring carry" part.